# Azure Mobile Apps - Custom authentication - Unable to login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm working in a Xamarin Forms mobile app with .NET background. I followed the guides as much as I could. But those are somehow uncompleted and there are not complete examples of custom authentication. I finally reach a point were I don't now how to advance. I can't make the login work.

I get this error after the client gets the respond of the LoginAsync:

```
     user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync("CustomAuth", credentials);
```

This is the error :

```
ex {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
```

If I use a default provider like Google+ works perfect. So I think the problem is in the backend. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I loop up the code several times and looks fine. 
I tried debugging the server side and I didn't get any error until it reaches the client side.

What Am I doing wrong?

This is my code in the server side.

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        if (isValidAssertion(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)) // user-defined function, checks against a database
        {
            JwtSecurityToken token = GetAuthenticationTokenForUser(loginRequest.username);

            return Ok(new
            {
                AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                User = new { UserId = loginRequest.username }
            });
        }
        else // user assertion was not valid
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

The auxiliar functions:

```
    private bool isValidAssertion(string username, string password)
    {
        AspNetUsers AspNetUser = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == username.ToLower());
        return AspNetUser != null && VerifyHashedPassword(AspNetUser.PasswordHash, password);
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken GetAuthenticationTokenForUser(string username)
    {
        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username)
        };

        string signingKey = "123456789123456789...";//Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
        string audience = "https://todo.azurewebsites.net/"; // audience must match the url of the site
        string issuer = "https://todo.azurewebsites.net/"; // audience must match the url of the site

        JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
            claims,
            signingKey,
            audience,
            issuer,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        );

        return token;
    }
```

In the Startup class I added:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomAuth", ".auth/login/CustomAuth", new { controller = "CustomAuth" });
```

And this is my code in the client side:

```
    public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        string username = "todo@gmail.com";
        string password = "todo";

        string message = string.Empty;
        var success = false;
        var credentials = new JObject
        {
            ["username"] = username,
            ["password"] = password
        };
        try
        {
            user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync("CustomAuth", credentials);
            if (user != null)
            {
                success = true;
                message = string.Format("You are now signed-in as {0}.", user.UserId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = string.Format("Authentication Failed: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        await new MessageDialog(message, "Sign-in result").ShowAsync();
        return success;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT (Solution):**

I'm gonna clarify for people with the same problem. The error was about some uppercase/lowercase differences. The names in the return must be "user", "userId" and "authenticationToken". Exactly like this:

```
        return Ok(new
        {
            authenticationToken = token.RawData,
            user = new { userId = loginRequest.username }
        });
```

Comment: What does the response look like when you POST with the username/password via Postman?  Also, after the POST, what does the client.CurrentUser object look like?  Is the Id and MobileServiceAuthenticationToken set?

Comment: Finally, if you use Postman to POST to your .auth/login/CustomAuth, then do a GET /tables/foo with X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to your authentication token, does it work?

Comment: In the firts scenario using postman I obtain a repond like: {"MobileServiceAuthenticationToken": "ey1234...", "UserId": "sid:1234..."} In the other hand the client.CurrentUser is set null and throws the exception. In the second case using the GET I get the 2 rows of the table.

Comment: Can you make sure TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient is not null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your response from the server is wrong.  Looking at a valid response, it looks like it needs to be:

```
{
    "user": "your-user-id",
    "authenticationToken": "the-jwt"
}
```

Correct the response from your server code and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh my gosh that was it. I tried with those words before but they fail me but now I know why. The error was a problem of uppercase/lowercase. The names must be "user", "userId" and "authenticationToken". Exactly like this. Thank you very very much.